# nginx: is there a fqdn version of $hostname?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to get nginx to match my host's full name (including domain name). as far as i can tell `$hostname` *only* includes the hostname, not the domain, so it's useless for this.

```
$ hostname -f
www.example.com
```

things i have tried:

```
server_name www.example.com          # works
server_name $hostname                # fails, only matches 'www'
server_name $hostname.example.com    # fails, doesn't match anything
server_name "$hostname.example.com"  # ditto
server_name ${hostname}.example.com  # ditto
server_name $(hostname).example.com  # ditto
```

beyond hard-coding my hostname into my nginx.conf file (which I need to avoid), what are my options here?

Comment: This sounds like you are using a Debian-based distribution, which is infamous for questionable design decisions such as not using the FQDN as the hostname (and for which they've put workarounds in many packages). But since nobody does this with nginx...

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can add the following line to your nginx startup script:

```
echo -e "server_name `hostname -f`;\n" > /etc/nginx/hostname.conf
```

and then use the `include hostname.conf;` directive in your nginx config file.